# C++ read in first item of line, check, then read in rest of items

Tags: c++

I have a file that looks like this:

```
# Some comments
Some data
```

Each line in the data section will have 5 items.

I would like to read in the file, line by line, but ignore the comments. To do this, I think I would need to check if the first item is a `#`. However, when I run the code below, I get a segmentation fault:

```
void readFile(string f, unordered_map<int, vector<double>> &l1, unordered_map<int, vector<double>> &l2,
              unordered_map<int, vector<double>> &l3) {
    ifstream          file(f);
    string first;
    int second;
    float third, fourth, fifth;

    string line;

    while(getline(file, line))
    {
        std::stringstream  lineStream(line);
        // Read an integer at a time from the line
        lineStream >> first;
        if (first == "#") { continue;}
        else {
            lineStream >> second >> third >> fourth >> fifth;
            vector<double> location {third, fourth, fifth};
            if (first == "sat") { l1[second].insert(l1[second].end(), location.begin(), location.end());
            } else if (first == "user") {l2[second].insert(l2[second].end(), location.begin(), location.end());
            } else {l3[second].insert(l3[second].end(), location.begin(), location.end());
            }
            cout << second << " " << third << " " << fourth << " " << fifth;
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: I've not written C++ for many years, but I don't think `lineStream >> first;` does what you seem to think it does. https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/

Comment: "*when I run the code below, I get a segmentation fault*" - one which line of code exactly? Please be more specific. Can you provide a [mcve] demonstrating how the function is being called? Also, why are you using a `vector` for `location` if it alway has 3 elements in it? A simpler `double[3]` or `std::array<double, 3>` would make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You have lineStream delcared as a stringstream. To use the extraction operator you need to declare it as an istringstream so you can read from it.

Change

```
std::stringstream lineStream(line);
```

to

```
std::istringstream lineStream(line);
```